# Python : How to easily track the module/function definition in big package

Tags: python, module

I'm new in coding. Let say i got a big python package contains many files and folder structures (contains many module). If  i open any random file and found custom functions/modules and want to know what their jobs and purposes. For simple example i  found this :

```
value = grabData(var)
```

i want to track this grabdata() , what the definition is or where it's located  etc. But sometimes this kind of functions is located on other files (via import). What is the easiest way to track them. Tracking backward using 'import' statement seems not efficient. Any tips ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a Python [integrated development environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) in your development workflow. IDEs often include features such as `Go To Declaration` or `Find Usages` that are accessible simply by right-clicking on the symbol you are looking for.

For example, here is how to `Find Usages` of a symbol in the PyCharm IDE: [link to PyCharm docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/finding-usages-in-project.html).

You can find a list of Python IDEs to install on the Python [community Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/IntegratedDevelopmentEnvironments).

Answer (score 1):

You nornally do not 'track' functions, but there should not be as much confusion: package is normally structured to make imports and locations easy to understand.

You can use any search tool that gives you entries of the function or class, eg as @Pierre suggests for Pycharm.

If you are interested about what the function, module or a class is, you can use:

- `dir`: `import re; dir(re)` - gives you a glimpse of methods available in a module or a class
- reading a docstring: `re.search.__doc__`
- using IPyhton 'magic' to learn about object: `re.search?`
- of course reading the docs ;)

Hope it helps.